# How do I add the "error" class when a form validation fails?

Tags: 7, webforms

I'm working with Drupal 7.56 and I am using the Webform module to create a custom form.

I used `hook_form_alter()` in a custom module to add a validation test.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id=='webform_client_form_1') {
    $form['#validate'][]='mymodule_form_validate';
    return $form;
  }
}

function mymodule_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $aux = $form_state['values']['submitted']['aux'];
  if ($aux != '') {
    if( /* my test */ ) {
      $text = t('Please check your input');
      form_set_error('aux', $text);
    }
  }
}
```

How can I add the *error* class when my test fails?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! I removed the second question since it was a different, unrelated question, that is probably already asked. What do you mean by _adding the "error" class_? You would not need to add a custom validation handler to verify the form field is not empty. Just mark the form field as requested, and the users would be requested to enter a value.

Comment: As side note, `hook_form_alter()` doesn't need to return the form. It is passed as reference.

Comment: Thank you. I have an other test then not empty.. I want to make the border of input red.. for requested input , the module add class error if field is empty.. I want to add the same class if my test is false.

Comment: $form['aux']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'error';  doesn't work!

Comment: $form['submitted']['aux']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'error'; doesn't work also! Any idea please? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First try removing your `if` test and see if you can get the `form_set_error` to trigger. That way you can make sure your test is correct. You should be able to call `form_set_error` in a validation function and it will work.

If that isn't the problem then make sure the name of your field is correct.

To answer the question about simply adding a class in form validation you can use the following:
`$form_state['complete form']['aux']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'error';`

It won't add to the input itself but to the field wrapper and you can style it from there. But I think figuring out why `form_set_error` isn't behaving how you want is your best bet. That should really be adding the error class.

Comment: Thank you! My test is correct because form_set_error works.. And I checked also my input's name and it's correct too!

Comment: @A.Sana Great, that's a good sign. So when you say `form_set_error` works what do you mean?

Comment: To answer the question about simply adding a class in form validation you can use the following `$form_state['complete form']['aux']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'error';`

Comment: Thanks @sagannotcarl, when I say form_set_error works, I want to say that my test is true.. Now what do you mean by "complete form" ? Is not 'submitted' ? Thank you

Comment: That's right. I tried that and `$form_state['completed form']` worked for me. Note that it's `$form_state` and not `$form` as well.

Comment: @A.Sana Did this work for you?

Comment: thank you for your attention. unfortunately not yet !!

Comment: @A.Sana: Can you describe exactly what happens when you call `form_set_error` in your validate function? Also what happens when you put `$form_state['complete form']['aux']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'error';` in a validate function?